# Integrate Admob to Android Problem

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am trying to integrate Admob to android, i end up with no success. The Document says Need to Provide DeviceID to get Ads for Real Devices.Could you please Help me about this. But I m getting ads in the Emulator by setting AdManager.TestEmulator.

Comment: regarding admob, you should check this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507516/admob-and-how-does-it-work/32963340#32963340

Answer (score 6):

It's fairly straight forward to setup with AdMob, I'm using it on several applications.  Once you define you application on the AdMob website/control panel you will see your unique ID for your application.

Then you just need to add the AdMob Jar to your project, assuming you're using eclipse easiest way is to create a libs folder in your project folder, copy the admob jar in there and from eclipse, right click it, and go to Build Path/Add to Build Path.

Then open your manifest file and add the following somewhere inside the  tag

```
<meta-data android:value="<YOUR APPLICATION ID FROM ADMOB CONTROL PANEL>" android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" />
```

Next decide which activity you wish the ad's to appear, I usually place the ad right at the bottom of a LinearLayout so add the following..

```
<com.admob.android.ads.AdView     
           android:id="@+id/ad" 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
           myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
           myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
  />
```

At the top of your layout definition where you define your xml namespace you will see

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

also add a reference to the admob namespace so you will have :

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/net.dbws.fv" **<-- change package (net.dbws.fv) to your package**
```

Finally create a file named **attrs.xml** in the values folder and insert the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <resources>
        <declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">            
           <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />
           <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color" />
           <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color" />
           <attr name="keywords" format="string" />
           <attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />
        </declare-styleable>
     </resources>
```

Then you should be good to go,  I certainly haven't needed to do anything different for real devices as opposed to the emulator, the above should work for you.  You don't always see ad's especially the first few times you run the app but if you are seeing ADMOB entries in your logcat output when you run your app then you can be confident it's working.

Regards

Comment: nice explanation Dave :) . thank you a lot , but i wanna just know where is the link to get the unique ID of adMob and where can i find the adMob.jar . thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

From the "Sites & Apps" overview when you're logged into AdMob, hover over the name of your app. You should see two buttons, "Reporting" and "Manage Settings".
Click on "Manage Settings". I think this is what they mean by the 'control panel'.

You'll see the "Publisher id" towards the top of the page. That's what you need for your AndroidManifest.xml file, to replace "YOUR_ID_HERE".

The string "ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID" remains exactly as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Hi dear find simple steps to add admob in your app...

1- Download GoogleAdMobAdsAdk-6.4.1.

2- Paste it to your lib folder.

3- go to https://apps.admob.com/?pli=1#monetize/adunit:create

4- get your **ID** from here by selecting Monetise a new app option.

5-  change your layout file-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >




     <com.google.ads.AdView
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:id="@+id/adView"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"

ads:adUnitId="Your Unit Id you generated"
 /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

6-
put these permission in android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

enjoy