# Android: how to integrate admob in app?

Tags: android, admob

I was trying to integrate admob banner in my application several hours, but I couldn't do that, so I created new app the only purpose of which is show admob banner but it doesn't work too. here is code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXX");
    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);
    setContentView(layout);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

and here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zzzzzz_admobtest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.zzzzzz_admobtest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
      android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Also, when I output adView.isActivated() and adView.isReady() they both are false.

I am using "XXX" instead of ID because I don't have one. Could it be a problem?

I am using device. Here is errors on ligcat

08-07 22:43:04.248: E/ActivityThread(24181): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
08-07 22:43:04.454: E/Ads(24181): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (http://media.admob.com/:1)
08-07 22:43:04.454: E/Web Console(24181): Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined at http://media.admob.com/:1

the last 2 errors could be fixed by this code

```
   (new Thread() {
        public void run() {
             Looper.prepare();
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        }
    }).start();
```

as I understand the first one is not an error but just a warning.
so why this isn't work??

Comment: I think you are checking this in your emulator if it is in emulator and wait for sometime

Comment: have you got any error in logcat

Answer (score 2):

> I am using "XXX" instead of ID because I don't have one. Could it be a
>   problem?

Yes. Absolutely yes. Sign up for an Admob account. Get yourself an ID and use that.

Comment: To find your app ID, click the App management option under the settings dropdown (located in the upper right-hand corner) on the AdMob account page. App IDs have the form ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX~NNNNNNNNNN.

Refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Answer (score 1):

Meta-Data Tag is missing inside the Android-manifest.look into the already available resources [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022051/integrate-admob-to-android-problem)

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"
            android:value="XXXX" />
```

Comment: Read @William answer, you are missing the basic step.This XXX needs to be your real Admob Application ID taken from your Admob account.

Answer (score 1):

This question is kinda old, but I want to answer it, because new technology appeared, which lets AdMob integration really easy. You don't need to code anything additionally in most cases, just create and .apk file and Admob will be injected into it automatically.

1. Enter [FGL Enhance](http://fgl.com/e4). Select, which SDK to integrate. You can select multiple various SDKs using this service, for this tutorial we'll pick only Admob from "I want to choose SDK myself".

Actually you can integrate more than 20 SDKs available by just selecting their checkbox. This list includes various ads providers, Crash reporting, Dolby Audio, etc.

2. Select, what development technology was used to build your app. If you want to show/hide the banner, you'll need to connect the lightweight drag-and-drop library and add 1 line of code. Depending on the technology you selected you'll be given a code sample and connector library download link.

But if you just want the banner to be present on your screen all the time, which is the easiest solution, you don't need to change your game code! This solution is called ZeroCode and it works for any development technology: event for the .apk and .ipa, which you've got from an HTML5-game or from Game Maker.

3. On this page you can select the ads types which will be shown in your app.
   Interstitial - ads between the levels
   Rewarded Video - videos, with a reward for viewing
   Flexible Banner - banner, which can be hidden/shown in the game code
   Persistent Banner - banner, which will stay on the screen all the time (but banner rotation is available, from AdMob settings)
   Pre-Roll - ads, shown as the app starts (like in ketchapp's games)

Two last types are marked as ZeroCode. You don't need to code anything in your game to have them integrated. For our sample we'll select just a Persistent banner.

4. Now upload our app.
5. On the next screen we can select a banner type. We can use, for example SMART_BANNER or any other banner type from AdMob help. We'll also input the banner id from our AdMob account. When creating a banner in AdMob account, we can set refresh interval.
6. The final step - signing method selection. You ca use your own developer's certificate, then you'll be able to submit the game to the store right after the AdMob has been injected. You can select a testing certificate to test the app on your own device. Or you can download an unsigned app and sign it locally before submitting to the store.
7. One more progress bar...

   And here we are!

The Enhance service is completely free for the developers. You'll receive the same amount of money from ads as if you'd integrated the ads manually. FGL receives the income from the SDK providers, because, in fact, FGL Enhance makes SDKs more attractive for the new developers.

source: http://www.airapport.com/2016/09/tutorial-how-to-quickly-integrate-admob.html

Answer (score 1):

how to integrate AdMob and Facebook banner ads into Android applications

**Build.Gradle :**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
```

**MyAplication.java:**

```
AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
     android:value="App_ID_Here.."/>    //Test App ID For Testing Purpose.
<activity
     android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

**Permission:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private LinearLayout bannerView;
    
            //Banner
        private AdView facebookAdView;
        private com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView admobAdView;
    
            //Interstitial
        private InterstitialAd facebookInterstitialAds;
        private com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd adMobInterstitialAds;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            bannerView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bannerView);
    
            //Load Banner Ads
            showFacebookBannerAds();
    
            //Load Interstitial Ads
            showFacebookInterstitial();
        }
    
        private void showFacebookBannerAds() {
    
            facebookAdView = new AdView(this, "Facebook_Banner_ID", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
            bannerView.addView(facebookAdView);
    
            facebookAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                    //If Load Fail then
                    showAdMobBanner();
                }
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                }
            });
    
            facebookAdView.loadAd();
        }
    
        private void showAdMobBanner() {
            admobAdView = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView(this);
            admobAdView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            admobAdView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
            bannerView.addView(admobAdView);
    
            admobAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    
    
        //Interstitial Ads
        private void showFacebookInterstitial() {
    
            facebookInterstitialAds = new InterstitialAd(this, "Interstitial_Ad_ID");
            facebookInterstitialAds.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                    //any work on ads close
                    finish();
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                   //if load fail then
                    loadAdMobInterstitial();
                }
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                    
                }
                @Override
                public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                }
            });
            facebookInterstitialAds.loadAd();
        }
    
        private void loadAdMobInterstitial() {
            adMobInterstitialAds = new com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd(this);
            adMobInterstitialAds.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
            adMobInterstitialAds.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    
            adMobInterstitialAds.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    super.onAdClosed();
                    //any work on ads close
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    
            //Interstitial Ads show on button click listener
    
        public void showAds(View view){
    
            if (facebookInterstitialAds.isAdLoaded())
                facebookInterstitialAds.show();
            else if (adMobInterstitialAds!=null)
                if (adMobInterstitialAds.isLoaded())
                    adMobInterstitialAds.show();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (admobAdView != null)
                admobAdView.pause();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (admobAdView != null)
                admobAdView.resume();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (facebookAdView != null)
                facebookAdView.destroy();
            if (admobAdView != null)
                admobAdView.destroy();
    
            if (facebookInterstitialAds != null)
                facebookInterstitialAds.destroy();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Just two line in your onCreate

```
AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

And add AddView in Your XML like

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ads_unit_id"
    ads:loadAdsOnCreate="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download complete source code from [here](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/integrating-google-admob-in-android-app/)

Add following lib in your dependency

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
```

For Smart Banner

Add following things in xml file

```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

Add following things in java file

```
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

For Interstitial Advertise

```
 mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.full_screen_ad_unit_id));

    AdRequest adRequestFull = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestFull);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            // Full screen advertise will show only after loading complete
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    });
```