# Android: add admob in application

Tags: android, admob

can somebody post here working code of application with integrated admob banner? I need just an application which will show admob banner nothing more. I was trying to write such thing and I posted another question ( [Android: how to integrate admob in app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095416/android-how-to-integrate-admob-in-app) )but nothing helps.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the below link it might help you :

1) http://mangaarun.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-integrate-admob-ads-in-android.html

2) http://jmsliu.com/209/add-google-admob-in-android-application.html

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this page for more help:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#android